# Update nvidia drivers with xorg-edgers ppa

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, gpu-driver

I wanted to update my nvidia drivers to version 337.19 with [this package](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/trusty/main/base/nvidia-graphics-drivers-337). I installed the PPA as described [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-337
```

However, it is unable to locate the package.

```
Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-337
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this procedure:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
```

The package name was wrong.