# NVIDIA drivers mystery!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-recommendation, gpu

I have had problems with NVIDIA drivers for a while.

Now I got a problem: In additional drivers I get `331.113`, as this link http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/80533/en-us shows, it is compatible with my `NVIDIA GeForce GT610 GF119 graphics card`.

But, when I search for my GPU on NVIDIA site (http://www.geforce.com/drivers), I don't get `331.113`.

**Is the `331.113` driver compatible [with my GPU]?**

**And, which driver works the best for my card and has the least bugs?**

*I'd really like to know that, as well as installation information.*

Comment: The 331.113 Nvidia drivers is compatible with the GeForce GT 610 graphics card. Also it might be worth upgrading to 346.35 as that is also compatible with your card and it is the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** According to Nvidia website, your video card has been supported since **295.53**

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.53-driver

> Added support for the following GPUs:
>
> ```
> GeForce GT 610
>   :
> ```

---

*Be slightly conservative.* You may want a later version (to better support your device), but do not want to be bleeding edge.

Unless you want to *always* download and compile (every OS update), use one of the provided PPAs.

See: [Update nvidia drivers with xorg-edgers ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464354/update-nvidia-drivers-with-xorg-edgers-ppa)

Use @robblue2x's method, and try **340.58**

Note: 331 is only 331.104 (not 311.113); and 346.nnn is *very latest*.

Comment: I get only nvidia-331 package in list, and it is 331.1130

Comment: http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/81252 is this driver bugless?

Comment: Don't know myself. Try: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers?dist=trusty