# Unable to Install NVIDIA Driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, lightdm

So I am trying to install the NVIDIA GPU Driver Version 346.35 (http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/81252) for my GTX 970 and am running into a lot of issues.  I have tried to run the file and get an error saying that I cannot install the driver while I am using X server.  I have searched for a fix to this and have had no luck, as the most common response is to stop lighdm from the terminal, however; when I do this my screen goes black and won't allow me to pull up a terminal, or do anything.  Help! I need 1080p!

I should  probably mention that the driver installation I performed a couple weeks ago when I initially installed Ubuntu had worked, but apparently stopped working recently and I am not sure why.  I think it was after I updated the driver on the Windows side or switched the port my monitor was plugged into, but I don't know enough to understand how either of these would affect my display on my Ubuntu OS.

Comment: @david6 The monitor is currently plugged in to the DVI-d port and I was previously using 1920x1080 but am now on 1024x768 as my driver is not installed properly/not working.  It is certainly possible that it is an entirely different issue, this is just what seems like the most likely cause to me, as the installation was a little fishy the first time as well.

Comment: I ran the commands from @robblue2x on this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464354/update-nvidia-drivers-with-xorg-edgers-ppa, however; this was the list I came up with:nvidia-331 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113
nvidia-331-updates - NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113

Comment: Did you complete first two steps? eg. **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update`**

Answer (score 0):

First try: [askubuntu > nvidia-drivers-mystery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577099/nvidia-drivers-mystery)

and use @robblue2x's method.

Finishing with **`sudo apt-get install nvidia-346`**

---

What screen resolution are you using? eg. **1920x1080 (Full HD), 2560x1600, 4K, etc.**

And what port/cable? eg. **DisplayPort, DVI Dual-Link, etc.**

---

**You may need to remove your earlier effort (driver download, from Nvidia).**

Also, do you even need a driver for **1920x1080**?

Does the 'inbuilt' Nouveau driver not work?

See: [nouveau > feature matrix](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix) and 'NV110' (right most) column.