# cannot get my nVidia drivers to install

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a problem with the Driver & update window. I can't install the proprietary nVidia drivers.

I select the top driver (a nVidia one) and hit apply. But it goes back to the 3rd option - Nouveau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a terminal.

Open terminal, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
```

Change `337` to any version you want - I'd recommend `304`, `331` or `349`. I'm using `349`.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464354/update-nvidia-drivers-with-xorg-edgers-ppa)

Comment: ok i think that was it