# Install nvidia geforce gt 845m driver on ubuntu 14.04.02 lts

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lightdm

I am trying to install the driver on my asus n551jq, under ubuntu 14.04.02 lts.

My steps are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-337
```

However, for the third step I get

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-337
```

As an alternative solution, I downloaded from nvidia website the driver NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-337.25.run,

```
 alt+ctrl+F1
```

I run

```
 sudo service lightdm stop
 sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-337.25.run
```

After the installation, I type:

```
 sudo service lightdm start
```

And a window appears with the message: "the system is running in low-graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.".

From this point on, it is not possible to enter to Ubuntu.

Comment: According to https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa ...337 is not a valid package.  Did you try nvidia-current to see which package is selected?

Comment: @ubfan1 According to http://askubuntu.com/a/471388/178235 , It's valid

Comment: Why do you try to install 337?

Answer (score 0):

**According to.. [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/nvidia-driver-337-25/)**

## 1. Run these in Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates-dev
```

> ***THEN RESTART YOUR COMPUTER***

## 2. Get the driver, run these intro Terminal too:

#### For 32-bit driver:

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/337.25/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-337.25.run
```

#### For 64-bit driver:

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/337.25/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-337.25.run
```

## 3. Switch command console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)

## 4. Run in Terminal:

#### By default:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

#### For Gnome GDM:

```
sudo service gdm stop
```

#### For Mint MDM:

```
sudo service mdm stop
```

## 5. Finally, permit and run the installer, run:

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-337.25.run && sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-337.25.run
```

Comment: After running the 5 steps, I reboot the system, and I am in a command console environment. If I try to exit from this environment a window appears with the message: "the system is running in low-graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.". So now I am afraid I have to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: @werty type 'reboot'

Comment: @werty, if it got even worse, try 'sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-337.25.run --uninstall' and then 'sudo apt-get remove nvidia-331-updates-dev' and then 'reboot'

Comment: Also replace '~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-337.25.run' with the path where you have downloaded the file

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: 'It does not work' is explaining nothing, I can't tell you do stuff without knowing what is the actual error, avoid 'It does not work' all-time while you're in SO