# Nvidia drivers cause Minecraft to crash

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, minecraft

I play Minecraft on my computer, and whenever I press F3, it says "Gallium 0.4 on NV98" I looked up what this means, and found out that it is a default graphics driver. So, I looked around for how to install the nvidia drivers for my computer, so I ran the command `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`. After doing this, when starting Minecraft again, a screen would quickly pop up twice, then it would crash with the following error log:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
[15:17:20] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: XXXXXXXX
[15:17:20] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
[15:17:22] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
[15:17:23] [Client thread/ERROR]: Couldn't set pixel format
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7fbce86da1d0 serial: 81 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) request_code: 155 minor_code: 24
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:521) [1.8.8.jar:?]
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363) [1.8.8.jar:?]
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310) [1.8.8.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [1.8.8.jar:?]
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// There are four lights!

Time: 8/19/15 3:17 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7fbce86da1d0 serial: 134 error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) request_code: 155 minor_code: 24
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:534)
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nCreate(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.create(LinuxContextImplementation.java:51)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.<init>(ContextGL.java:132)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:850)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at ave.ap(SourceFile:534)
    at ave.am(SourceFile:363)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at ave.a(SourceFile:310)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.8
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.19.0-15-generic
    Java Version: 1.7.0_79, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 72926576 bytes (69 MB) / 176979968 bytes (168 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.8.8
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
#@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# /home/mayatta65/.minecraft/crash-reports/crash-2015-08-19_15.17.24-client.txt
[15:17:24] [Client Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server
```

After doing that, I had to uninstall the packages so that it would fall back to the Gallium 0.4 driver. How can I install the Nvidia drivers and get Minecraft to work?

Comment: Which version of the driver do you have currently? Run `dpkg -l | grep -oP nvidia-[0-9]{3}`

Comment: `nvidia-304` is the current version.

Comment: Okay, you probably want a later version - I'm on `nvidia-349` atm.

Comment: How will I get a later version?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464354/update-nvidia-drivers-with-xorg-edgers-ppa Sorry, it took me a while to find the link... I still think there is a better one

Comment: Thank you, I was able to install Nvidia 355, I'm going to see if it works.

Comment: 355 is still in beta, so if it doesn't 349 may be the best for you. If not, work your way through them!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27164/discussion-between-dorian-dore-and-tim).

Comment: A reboot cleared up my issue.

Comment: Possibly a reboot will correct things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Minecraft but if you want to install Nvidia driver, take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120955/ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-installation/176546#176546) question.

To make it short, you should go to ***additional driver***, choose the driver which is ***proprietary*** and ***tested***. Then install **`nvidia-prime`** package.

Comment: Tried that, still gets the same error. And it's not only with Minecraft, after doing `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils && glxinfo` I get the same error.